# Object of arrays and text files

Tags: java

I am creating a Java program where there is a text file called cars that has an unknown number of lines. The lines are formatted as car type, year, model, car code(s). Car code(s) can be be zero or higher. These need to be stored in an array of objects to be called later. However, `carCode` only prints out 0 and nothing is being stored. car type, year and model also need to be in the same array of objects so that when the year is called the model, car type and carCode for that year is shown. However, only the last one is shown. Please help me understand where I am going wrong.

I have got

```
File cars = new File("cars.txt");
scanner scanLine = new Scanner(cars);
while(scanLine.hasNextLine()) {     
    String line = scanLine.nextLine();
    String [] cars = line.split(","); 
    carType = cars[0];
    year = Integer.parseInt(cars[1]);
    model = cars[2];
    while(scanLine.hasNextInt()) {
        carCode[count] = Integer.parseInt[3 + count2];
        count++;
        count2++
    }
    count2 =0; 
}
```

the text file has this in its first 3 lines

> Ford, 2008, ford focus, 243423
>     Honda, 2007, civic, 324233,1342354, , 2343234
>     kia ,2010, rio

Answer (score 1):

Your car codes are part of the line that you read into the `line` String and split into the `cars` array, so you should extract them from that array, and not attempt to get more input from the file (which would give you data from the next line of the file).

```
 if (cars.length > 3) {
     carCode = new int[cars.length-3];
     for (int i=3;i<cars.length;i++)
     {
          carCode[i-3] = Integer.parseInt(cars[i]);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is that you are reading the whole line, then trying to scan  for `integers`, but the `integers` are already in the line that you have read.

As these `integers` will already be the the `cars` array, you can simply loop and get the value using `Integer.parseInt(cars[i]);`

Also you can ready till the end of the array, you can do

```
carCode[] = new Integer [cars.length - 3];

for (int i = 3; i < cars.length; i++)
{
      carCode[count] = Integer.parseInt(cars[i]);
      count++;
}
```

Comment: Is `new Integer [cars.length - 3] ()` even valid syntax?

Comment: I removed the syntax error from your code. If you feel I changed too much revert.

Comment: @SecondRikudo Thanks for the edit.  A bad C&P as I was rushing out the door.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following program, It is working:

```
File cars = new File("C:\\Users\\u0148311\\Desktop\\cars.txt");
Scanner scanLine = new Scanner(cars);
while(scanLine.hasNextLine())   {
String line = scanLine.nextLine();
String [] carArray = line.split(",");
int count = carArray.length;
String carType = carArray[0].trim();
int year = Integer.parseInt(carArray[1].trim());
String model = carArray[2].trim();
 if(count> 2){
  String [] carCodeArray = new String[count-3];
     for(int i=3; i<count; i++){
         carCodeArray[i-3]= carArray[i].trim();
     }
for(String str:carCodeArray) 
     System.out.print(str+" ");
 }
 System.out.println("");
}
```

}

Comment: atleast explain what is wrong with the OP's code and how you resolve it

Comment: thank you it worked for car code however car type, year and model also need to be in the same array of objects so that when the year is called the model, car type and carCode for that year is shown however only the last one is shown